# Как передать в render данные которые уже загрузились

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты, render, mobx

Мне поступила задача создать новый компонент, что бы он рендерил данные которые пришли мне с бэка
Характеристики компа пользователя

Я реализовал функцию load которая получает get запросом данные, распаршивает и засовывает в переменную
После сделал метод который содержит в себе модальное конфиг для модального окна (это не совсем важно думаю)
Имеется конечно же constructor в котором я идентефицирую this.data = null;
Сделал я это для того что бы теперь в нее записывать данные пришедшие с бэка

Вопрос вот в чем!
Внутри render () я создал массив внутри которого объекты, что бы эти данные отображались на странице.
Но есть данные Nics которых может придти много, а может очень монго. И захотел я написать функцию метод, которая будет перебирать пришедшие данные и отображать. Спасибо форуму, помогли с функцией.

Но теперь вставляя ее в свой массив объектов, получаю ошибку, что не читаются данные из за того, что при асинхронной работе не успевает прогрузиться data и я получаю undefined

Помогите пожалуйста, как мне правильно в рендер прокидывать данные, что бы они всегда приходили туда прогрузившимися и я мог работать с ЯВНОЙ логикой.
Код прилагаю

```
@inject('locale', 'modal', 'form', 'ajax')
@observer
export default class Hardware extends React.Component
{

  @observable loading = true;


  async load() {
    const {ajax, form} = this.props;
    this.loading = true;

    const d = await ajax.get('system/stats');
    this.data = JSON.parse(d);

    this.loading = false;
  } 

  extract (devises) {
    if(this.data && this.data.hardware.nics)
    {
      const out = [];
    for (let name in devises) {
      const value = devises[name];
      out.push({ name, value });
    }
    return out;
    }   
  };

  getNics(dat) {
    if(this.data && this.data.hardware.nics) {
      let temp = [];
      for(let [n, v] of Object.entries(dat))
          temp.push({name: n, value: v});
      return temp;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = null;

    
  }

  async modalGo() {
    const {ajax, form} = this.props;
    this.loading = true;

    const cfgF = {
      form: {
        items: [
        {
          name: 'firmaname', 
          title: 'Название организации', 
          onChange: (v) => {
            v.length >= 10 ? form.setError('firmaname', false) : form.setError('firmaname', 'Не менее 10 символов')
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'companyEmail', 
          title: 'E-mail организации', 
          validTypes: ['email'],
          required: true,
          validate: (v) => {
            const hostname = Stores.form.values.hostname;
            if(v.substring(v.indexOf('.')) === hostname.substring(hostname.indexOf('.')).trim()) {
              form.setError('hostname', false);
              form.setError('companyEmail', false);
              
            } else {
              form.setError('hostname', 'email и имя имеют единый домен');
              form.setError('companyEmail', 'email и имя системы имеют единый домен');
              
            }
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'hostname', 
          title: 'Имя системы', 
          validTypes: ['host'],
          required: true,
          validate: (v) => {
            const comEmail = Stores.form.values.companyEmail;
            if(v.substring(v.indexOf('.')) === comEmail.substring(comEmail.indexOf('.')).trim()) {
              form.setError('hostname', false);
              form.setError('companyEmail', false);
            } else {
              form.setError('hostname', 'email и имя имеют единый домен');
              form.setError('companyEmail', 'email и имя системы имеют единый домен');
            }
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'error', 
          title: 'Ошибка'
        },
      ]},
      modal: {title: 'Система'}
    };    
    form.clear();

    const result = await this.props.modal.show(cfgF, async(btn, win) => {

      let data = await ajax.get('system');

      if (btn.ok) {
        try {
           await ajax.post('system', {
            'firmaname': data.firmaname,
            'companyEmail': data.companyEmail,
            'hostname': data.hostname,
            'error': data.error
            });          
        } catch (e) {
          let error = Utils.exception(e);
          if (error && typeof (error) === 'string') {
            if(error === 'error1')
              return this.props.modal.error("Произошла ошибка 1");
            else if (error === 'error2')
              return this.props.modal.error("Произошла ошибка 2");
            else {
              return this.props.modal.error("Не удалось сохранить");
            }
          }
        }
      } 
      if (btn.cancel) {
        this.load();
        return true;
      }
      this.loading = false;
    })
    if (result) 
      return true;
    
    this.loading = false;
  }  

     
  componentDidMount(){
    this.load();
  }

  render() {
    
    const {loading} = this;

    if(this.data) {
      console.log(this.data.hardware.nics);
      console.log(this.extract(this.data.hardware.nics));
      console.log(this.getNics(this.data.hardware.nics));
    }

    let hardwares = [
      
      {title: 'CPU'},
      '->',
      {name: 'Model', value: this.data ? this.data.hardware.cpu.model : null},
      {name: 'Arch', value: this.data ? this.data.hardware.cpu.arch : null},
      {name: 'Memory', value: this.data ? Math.round(this.data.hardware.memory / 1073741824) + 'Gb' : null},
      '-',
      {title: 'Nics'},
      '->',
      // this.extract(this.data.hardware.nics),
      // {name: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.keys(this.data.hardware.nics)[0] : null,
      //   value: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.values(this.data.hardware.nics)[0] : null},
      // {name: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.keys(this.data.hardware.nics)[1] : null,
      //   value: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.values(this.data.hardware.nics)[1] : null},
      // {name: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.keys(this.data.hardware.nics)[2] : null,
      //   value: this.data && this.data.hardware.nics ? Object.values(this.data.hardware.nics)[2] : null},
      '-',
      {title: 'System'},
      '->',
      {name: 'Version', value: this.data ? this.data.system.license.version : null},
      {name: 'Serial', value: this.data ? this.data.system.license.serial : null},
      {name: 'ip', value: this.data ? this.data.ip : null},
    ];

     
    return (
      <div  className="ui divided list" style={{margin: "1.8rem 0 0"}}>
        <Panel loading={loading}>
          <Summary loading={loading} items={hardwares} />
        </Panel>
        <Button  title='Система' style={{marginTop: '2em'}} onClick={() => {this.modalGo()}} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: До тех пор пока данные не пришли, вам нужно показывать ```preloader```. После того, как данные пришли Вам нужно положить их в ```this.state```, а не просто в переменную ```this.data```. Как только реакт увидит, что ```this.state``` обновился он заново отрисует компонент, но уже с отображаемыми данными.